# JPA merge does insert new entity instead of update existing one

Tags: jpa, ejb

It seems like that when I update my existing entity using jpa merge, it does insert entity with same id instead of updating existing one expected. Because after insertion, database row order lost. But I still have same entities with same ids, does Jpa use insertion to update? I mean does it delete existing entity and insert again with updated value to do its update job. Main chaos is database order is lost then.

Here is my listener method: userService Is EJB class within I use JPA.

```
public void onEditUserOrganization(RowEditEvent event){
    UserOrganization uorg =(UserOrganization) event.getObject();
    try {

    userService.updateUserOrganization(uorg);

    } catch (UserException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("error)"));
    }finally{
        parentlist = getUserOrganizationParents();
        branchlist = getUserOrganizationBranches();
    }
}
```

Here is my main update method

```
    @Override
public void updateUserOrganization(UserOrganization org) throws UserException{
    if(org != null && !em.contains(org)){
    try{

        UserOrganization existing = em.find(UserOrganization.class, org.getUorgId());
        existing.setOrgcode(org.getOrgcode());
        existing.setOrgname(org.getOrgname());
        existing.setParent(org.getParent());


    }catch(Exception e){
    throw new UserException("Couldn't update user org with id " + org.getUorgId());
    }
    }
}
```

Here is my entity class:

```
public class UserOrganization implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Column(name = "uorg_id", nullable = false)
private Integer uorgId;
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Column(name = "parent", nullable = false)
private short parent;
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Size(min = 1, max = 10)
@Column(name = "orgcode", nullable = false, length = 10)
private String orgcode;
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Size(min = 1, max = 150)
@Column(name = "orgname", nullable = false, length = 150)
private String orgname;
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "uorgId")
private List<refMain> refList;
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "uorgId")
private List<User1> user1List;
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "userOrganization")
private List<Bankrelation> relationList;


public UserOrganization() {
}

//getter setters..
    @Override
public boolean equals(Object object) {
    // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
    if (!(object instanceof UserOrganization)) {
        return false;
    }
    UserOrganization other = (UserOrganization) object;
    if ((this.uorgId == null && other.uorgId != null) || (this.uorgId != null && !this.uorgId.equals(other.uorgId))) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "mn.bs.crasmon.model.UserOrganization[ uorgId=" + uorgId + " ]";
}
```

What is the best way to do update In JPA

Comment: Show us the entity class. Are you overriding `hashCode` and `equals`?

Comment: yes there are hashCode and equals methods. I autogenerated entities from database using netbeans ide.

Comment: You're not calling merge() anywhere in the code you posted. Do you see insert queries being executed? Which one? And when executing which code? Anyway, you should never rely on row order. If you want your rows sorted, use an `order by` in your query.

Comment: I thought that in my update method jpa method 'find' would return entity that is in persistence context at that time. So after I swapped it's properties with new ones method transaction ends and commits that entity would automatically flushed to database, updated.